# How to run NVPROF that contains no CUDA code?

Tags: openacc

Want to baseline a standard fortran code that does not contain cuda code before I upgrade it.  Can I do that and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you have CUDA 7.5 you can do the following.

```
nvprof --cpu-profiling on ./a.out
```